# Azure DevOps Artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am new to Azure DevOps (Hosted Agent) and am trying to use the Azure Pipelines to build my Java web app using Ant

below is the pipeline file

```
trigger:
- azure-pipelines

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Ant@1
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    buildFile: 'ant/build.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
```

Project got build successfully but the path of the WAR file is shown as

Building war: /home/vsts/work/1/s/war/Project.war

I am not able find `/home/vsts/work/1/s` path in Azure DevOps, I tried to search under Artifact but not found, How can I access the `/home/vsts/work/1/s` so that I can get my WAR file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Publish Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task in order to be able to obtain the results of your build.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' # or your build results directory 
    artifactName: 'drop' 
    #publishLocation: 'Container' # Options: container, filePath
    #targetPath: # Required when publishLocation == FilePath
    #parallel: false # Optional
    #parallelCount: # Optional
    #fileCopyOptions: #Optional
```